# How to set property scope in SoapUI, using groovy script?

Tags: groovy, soapui, load-testing

I'd like to set a property in the testCase scope using a Groovy script. I tried to do this as follows:

`def tc = testRunner.testCase
tc.setPropertyValue("{#TestCase#status}", status)`

but it creates only a property with the name

> {#TestCase#status}

So how to set the testCase scope?

The problem is that if I set this request status to a property then it gets overwritten by another thread during load tests (so my assertion fails)

Comment: Here is how you can set `testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('PROPERTY_NAME', 'PROPERTY_VALUE')` or `context.testCase.setPropertyValue('PROPERTY_NAME', 'PROPERTY_VALUE')`. And you have to use ${#TestCase#PROPERTY_NAME} to access in later steps.

Answer (score 1):

A little change is needed :)

```
def tc = testRunner.testCase

// if you want to set a property with a name - PropertyName with the value - 123 then,
tc.setPropertyValue("PropertyName", "123")

// Your case, tc.setPropertyValue("status", "Pass")
```